# Ajax.ActionLink works In IE but not in Chrome ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I have an `Ajax.ActionLink(...)` retrieving some view html and populating div (`id='divResults'`) with results:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.DisplayName, "Edit", "Act", 
    new { id = item.Id }, 
    new AjaxOptions { 
           UpdateTargetId = "divResults", 
           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
           OnBegin = "loading('divResults')" 
    }, 
    new { @class = "abc" }
)
```

All this works nicely in IE 11 and Firefox, **but not in Chrome**. When I test it in Chrome and click on the Ajax link, it gets the results but instead of populating `divResults` it shows a new page with the retrieved content.

This is an MVC 5 project.

Already included are:

- jquery-1.11.3.js
- jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
- jquery.validate.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

As mentioned above, it all works in IE 11. Has any one had similar issues on Chrome and managed to fix? Thanks!

**Update**

- `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled`  is true
- Cache cleared
- just tested on Firefox 43.0.3 and it works!! IE 11 works, **just not working in Chrome** (tested version 47.0.2526.106 m)
- Just tested another project and it doesn't work in Chrome either.

Comment: Can you try to clear the browser cache in IE and try again ? If it works, Clear the cache of chrome and try

Comment: Do you have the `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` config setting saved as `true`?

Comment: UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled is true already set and cache is already cleared

Comment: Any errors in the dev console? Have you disabled JavaScript in Chrome?

Comment: Do you get an error message in the Console on Chrome? Also, there could be something wrong with your div structure that's ignored by the other browsers, but not by Chrome.

Comment: Great! "Have you disabled JavaScript in Chrome?" Must have done it last year it remembered after Happy new year holidays. Thanks!